# after groupby and sum,how to get the max value rows in `pandas.DataFrame`?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

here the df(i updated by real data ):

```
>TIMESTAMP          OLTPSOURCE      RNR                         RQDRECORD
>20150425232836     0PU_IS_PS_44    REQU_51NHAJUV06IMMP16BVE572JM2  17020
>20150128165726     ZFI_DS41        REQU_50P1AABLYXE86KYE3O6EY390M  6925
>20150701144253     ZZZJB_TEXT      REQU_52DV5FB812JCDXDVIV9P35DGM  2
>20150107201358     0EQUIPMENT_ATTR     REQU_50EVHXSDOITYUQLP4L8UXOBT6  14205
>20150623215202     0CO_OM_CCA_1     REQU_528XSXYWTK6FSJXDQY2ROQQ4Q 0
>20150715144139     0HRPOSITION_TEXT    REQU_52I9KQ1LN4ZWTNIP0N1R68NDY  25381
>20150625175157     0HR_PA_0    REQU_528ZS1RFN0N3Y3AEB48UDCUKQ  100020
>20150309153828     0HR_PA_0    REQU_51385K5F3AGGFVCGHU997QF9M  0
>20150626185531     0FI_AA_001  REQU_52BO3RJCOG4JGHEIIZMJP9V4A  0
>20150307222336     0FUNCT_LOC_ATTR REQU_513JJ6I6ER5ZVW5CAJMVSKAJQ  13889
>20150630163419     0WBS_ELEMT_ATTR REQU_52CUPVUFCY2DDOG6SPQ1XOYQ2  0
>20150424162226     6DB_V_DGP_EXPORTDATA    REQU_51N1F5ZC8G3LW68E4TFXRGH9I  0
>20150617143720     ZRZMS_TEXT  REQU_5268R1YE6G1U7HUK971LX1FPM  6
>20150405162213     0HR_PA_0    REQU_51FFR7T4YQ2F766PFY0W9WUDM  0
>20150202165933     ZFI_DS41    REQU_50QPTCF0VPGLBYM9MGFXMWHGM  6925
>20150102162140     0HR_PA_0    REQU_50CNUT7I9OXH2WSNLC4WTUZ7U  0
>20150417184916     0FI_AA_004  REQU_51KFWWT6PPTI5X44D3MWD7CYU  0
>20150416220451     0FUNCT_LOC_ATTR REQU_51JP3BDCD6TUOBL2GK9ZE35UU  13889
>20150205150633     ZHR_DS09    REQU_50RFRYRADMA9QXB1PW4PRF5XM  6667
>20150419230724     0PU_IS_PS_44    REQU_51LC5XX6VWEERAVHEFJ9K5A6I  22528

>and the relationships between columns is
>OLTPSOURCE--RNR:1>n
>RNR--RQDRECORD:1>N
```

> and my requirement is:

1. sum the RQDRECORD by RNR;
2. get the max sum result of every OLTPSOURCE;
3. Finally, I would draw a graph showing the results of all
   sumed largest OLTPSOURCE by time

Thanks everyone, I further explain my problem:

1. if OLTPSOURCE:RNR:RQDRECORD= 1:1:1

   > just sum RQDRECORD,RETURN OLTPSOURCE AND SUM RESULT
2. if OLTPSOURCE:RNR:RQDRECORD= 1:1:N

   > just sum RQDRECORD,RETURN OLTPSOURCE AND SUM RESULT
3. if OLTPSOURCE:RNR:RQDRECORD= 1:N:(N OR 1)

   > sum RQDRECORD by RNR GROUP first,THEN Find the max result of one OLTPSOURCE,return all the OLTPSOURCE with the max RQDRECORD .

So for the above sample data, I eventually want the result as follows

```
>TIMESTAMP  OLTPSOURCE  RNR RQDRECORD
>20150623215202     0CO_OM_CCA_1    REQU_528XSXYWTK6FSJXDQY2ROQQ4Q  0
>20150107201358     0EQUIPMENT_ATTR REQU_50EVHXSDOITYUQLP4L8UXOBT6  14205
>20150626185531     0FI_AA_001  REQU_52BO3RJCOG4JGHEIIZMJP9V4A  0
>20150417184916     0FI_AA_004  REQU_51KFWWT6PPTI5X44D3MWD7CYU  0
>20150416220451     0FUNCT_LOC_ATTR REQU_51JP3BDCD6TUOBL2GK9ZE35UU  13889
>20150625175157     0HR_PA_0    REQU_528ZS1RFN0N3Y3AEB48UDCUKQ  100020
>20150715144139     0HRPOSITION_TEXT    REQU_52I9KQ1LN4ZWTNIP0N1R68NDY  25381
>20150419230724     0PU_IS_PS_44    REQU_51LC5XX6VWEERAVHEFJ9K5A6I  22528
>20150630163419     0WBS_ELEMT_ATTR REQU_52CUPVUFCY2DDOG6SPQ1XOYQ2  0
>20150424162226     6DB_V_DGP_EXPORTDATA    REQU_51N1F5ZC8G3LW68E4TFXRGH9I  0
>20150202165933     ZFI_DS41    REQU_50QPTCF0VPGLBYM9MGFXMWHGM  6925
>20150205150633     ZHR_DS09    REQU_50RFRYRADMA9QXB1PW4PRF5XM  6667
>20150617143720     ZRZMS_TEXT  REQU_5268R1YE6G1U7HUK971LX1FPM  6
>20150701144253     ZZZJB_TEXT  REQU_52DV5FB812JCDXDVIV9P35DGM  2
```

Referring to EdChum's approach, I made some adjustments, the results were as follows, because the amount of data is too big, I did "'RQDRECORD> 100000'" is set, in fact I would like to sort and then take the top 100, but not success

> [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ZXju.jpg "result"

Comment: whoa, just post what you had before, only put explicitly that you have a timestamp index.

Comment: sorry,I am a newcomer

Comment: It should be 1 problem per question, also you state you want to sum by 'RNR' but in your sample data their all unique, you should be able to modify my answer to get what you want, you'll lose the timestamps for some reason but it may be better to not set this as the index and then set it to the index after merging

Answer (score 0):

You can take the groupby result, call [`max`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.max.html#pandas.DataFrame.max) on this and pass param `level=0` or `level='clsa'` if you prefer, this will return you the max count for that level. However this loses the 'clsb' column so what you can do is `merge` this back to your grouped result after calling `reset_index` on the grouped object, you can reorder the resulting df columns by using fancy indexing:

```
In [149]:
gp = df.groupby(['clsa','clsb']).sum()
result = gp.max(level=0).reset_index().merge(gp.reset_index())
result = result.ix[:,['clsa','clsb','count']]
result

Out[149]:
  clsa clsb  count
0    a   a1      9
1    b   b2      8
2    c   c2     10
```

Comment: thanks!but i want get only the max top one result of every grouped

Comment: I'm sorry I did not make clear, in fact, there is a timestamp column as index, if use re_index, on the failure of the original index。 the original DF is this four columns:time,clsa,clsb,count,and i had do "df.set_index('time',inplace=True)"

Comment: Well it would help if you actually posted what your data looked like and what you **really** want

Comment: hi,EdChum,I updated my question, please help me have another look

Answer (score 0):

```
df['TIMESTAMP'] = pd.to_datetime(df['TIMESTAMP'], format='%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
df_gb = df.groupby(['OLTPSOURCE', 'RNR'], as_index=False).aggregate(sum)
final = pd.merge(df[['TIMESTAMP', 'OLTPSOURCE', 'RNR']], df_gb.groupby(['OLTPSOURCE'], as_index=False).first(), on=['OLTPSOURCE', 'RNR'], how='right').sort('OLTPSOURCE')
final.plot(kind='bar')
plt.show()


print final

             TIMESTAMP            OLTPSOURCE                             RNR  \
3  2015-06-23 21:52:02          0CO_OM_CCA_1  REQU_528XSXYWTK6FSJXDQY2ROQQ4Q   
2  2015-01-07 20:13:58       0EQUIPMENT_ATTR  REQU_50EVHXSDOITYUQLP4L8UXOBT6   
5  2015-06-26 18:55:31            0FI_AA_001  REQU_52BO3RJCOG4JGHEIIZMJP9V4A   
11 2015-04-17 18:49:16            0FI_AA_004  REQU_51KFWWT6PPTI5X44D3MWD7CYU   
6  2015-03-07 22:23:36       0FUNCT_LOC_ATTR  REQU_513JJ6I6ER5ZVW5CAJMVSKAJQ   
4  2015-07-15 14:41:39      0HRPOSITION_TEXT  REQU_52I9KQ1LN4ZWTNIP0N1R68NDY   
10 2015-01-02 16:21:40              0HR_PA_0  REQU_50CNUT7I9OXH2WSNLC4WTUZ7U   
13 2015-04-19 23:07:24          0PU_IS_PS_44  REQU_51LC5XX6VWEERAVHEFJ9K5A6I   
7  2015-06-30 16:34:19       0WBS_ELEMT_ATTR  REQU_52CUPVUFCY2DDOG6SPQ1XOYQ2   
8  2015-04-24 16:22:26  6DB_V_DGP_EXPORTDATA  REQU_51N1F5ZC8G3LW68E4TFXRGH9I   
0  2015-01-28 16:57:26              ZFI_DS41  REQU_50P1AABLYXE86KYE3O6EY390M   
12 2015-02-05 15:06:33              ZHR_DS09  REQU_50RFRYRADMA9QXB1PW4PRF5XM   
9  2015-06-17 14:37:20            ZRZMS_TEXT  REQU_5268R1YE6G1U7HUK971LX1FPM   
1  2015-07-01 14:42:53            ZZZJB_TEXT  REQU_52DV5FB812JCDXDVIV9P35DGM   

    RQDRECORD  
3           0  
2       14205  
5           0  
11          0  
6       13889  
4       25381  
10          0  
13      22528  
7           0  
8           0  
0        6925  
12       6667  
9           6  
1           2
```