# returning only the maximum values after grouping in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

The question I'm trying to solve is to find the products with the slowest shipping speed.

the first step I did was to find the mean shipping speed for the products using the following code

`westData.groupby('Product ID')['Shipping Speed'].agg(lambda x: x.mean())`

and the result I have is in the following format

[image: mean shipping speed per product]

now I'm trying to filter the results to get only the results with the slowest shipping speed. in other words, return only the values that equal the maximum mean from the shipping speed column.

in my case the slowest shipping speed is

`westData.groupby('Product ID')['Shipping Speed'].agg(lambda x: x.mean()).max()`

Timedelta('7 days 00:00:00')

So I need to return only the products with the shipping speed of ('7 days 00:00:00')

which should be like the following

[image: required output]

Comment: Pls explain better what are you after. What does the code you posted output?

Comment: have you read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31581537/after-groupby-and-sum-how-to-get-the-max-value-rows-in-pandas-dataframe/31581568) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15705630/get-the-rows-which-have-the-max-count-in-groups-using-groupby)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you get the `mean`

```
s = westData.groupby('Product ID')['Shipping Speed'].mean()
```

Filter with `max`

```
s = s[s==s.max()]
items = s.index.tolist()
```

Comment: @AnasBaheh you can just do s[s==s.max()]